# Unexpected End of input for function in brackets. Why?

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

I am doing a vanilla Javascript practice but I kept getting the error that says Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input.

I don't understand what is going on, because the code seems fine to me.

Can someone help me with this? Thanks in advance for any assistance rendered.

HTML:

```
`<div class="foot">
  <h1>Eleemo<wrap class="yol">synary</wrap></h1>
                <h2 class="stash">Welcome</h2>
  <p class="stash">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

</div>
<div class="foot" class='stash'>
  <p class="stash" class="indi">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Cras pulvinar mattis nunc sed blandit. Adipiscing elit pellentesque habitant morbi tristique. Ultrices vitae auctor eu augue ut lectus arcu. Habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada. Ullamcorper sit amet risus nullam eget. In vitae turpis massa sed. Tristique senectus et netus et malesuada. Varius vel pharetra vel turpis nunc eget lorem dolor sed. Arcu bibendum at varius vel pharetra vel. Non pulvinar neque laoreet suspendisse interdum consectetur libero. Libero id faucibus nisl tincidunt eget nullam non. Integer vitae justo eget magna fermentum iaculis.</p>
</div>
<div class="straw">
  <button class="headx">Let's Begin</button>
</div>`
```

JS:

```
(function() {   var elements;   var winHeight;

  function init() {
    elements = document.querySelectorAll('.stash');
    windowHeight = window.innerHeight;   }

  function checkPosition() {
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      var element = elements[i];
      var positionFromTop = elements[i].getBoundingClientRect().top;

      if (positionFromTop - winHeight <= -80) {
        element.classList.add('fadeo');
        element.classList.remove('stash');
      }else{
        element.classList.add('stash');
        element.classList.remove('fadeo');
      }
    }   }

  window.addEventListener('scroll', checkPosition);   window.addEventListener('resize', init);

  init();   checkPosition(); });

   function apple(){   if(document.querySelectorAll(".indi")[0].style.opacity==1){
    document.querySelectorAll(".straw").classList.add("woops");   }
```

Comment: Your brackets aren't balanced.

Comment: where? I didn't notice any.

Comment: Use proper indentation - one statement per line. Then you will see what's missing. I see that `apple` function does not have ending `}`

Comment: Use an editor that automatically indents your code and inserts brackets.

Comment: Please indent your code before asking and try to ask well constructed questions, this is very difficult to decipher and your code should always follow good styling to help with problems exactly as this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
(function() {
    var elements;
    var winHeight;

    function init() {
        elements = document.querySelectorAll('.stash');
        windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
    }

    function checkPosition() {
        for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            var element = elements[i];
            var positionFromTop = elements[i].getBoundingClientRect().top;

            if (positionFromTop - winHeight <= -80) {
                element.classList.add('fadeo');
                element.classList.remove('stash');
            } else {
                element.classList.add('stash');
                element.classList.remove('fadeo');
            }
        }
    }

    window.addEventListener('scroll', checkPosition);
    window.addEventListener('resize', init);

    init();
    checkPosition();
});

function apple() {
    if (document.querySelectorAll(".indi")[0].style.opacity == 1) {
        document.querySelectorAll(".straw").classList.add("woops");
    }
    }
```

you were just missing last closing `}`